# Call a function just after application is completely loaded (jQuery mobile and PhoneGap)

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following problem with my application (jQuery-mobile with Phonegap)

I need to call a function with a ajax call, that returns a URL of a image, after load the json response take the URL and load an image on top of the main screen.

My problem is, because the screen is the first screen after application loaded, the user see and wait in the splash screen and after, the application show the page full rendered instantally.

My application on Blackberry devices delay more that 10s on the splash screen, but, I comment the ajax code, the app loads in 4s.

I tried to put the function in:
..live("pageaftershow", function().. with same result, always call the function, parse json and load image BEFORE the user see the screen.

How can I make sure that this function call effectively after the user see the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are making an ajax call in the script tag of your page before the onLoad event then you are going to delay the display of your page until the ajax request completes. You should really wait for deviceready before making that ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

try doing the ajax call on deviceready

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
// do stuff
},false);
```